# Access Div tag inside TD with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table with the following structure.

```
 <table id="items">
     <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>SlNo</th>
            <th>Item</th>
            <th>Unit Cost</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="item-row">
            <td class="item-name">
            <div class="delete-wpr"><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="slno"/></td>           
            <td><input type="text" class="cost"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="qty"/></td>
            <!--  <td><span class="price"></span></td>-->
            <td class="price"> </td>
        </tr>
        <input type="button" id="example" value="submit" onClick="storeAndShowTableValues()"/>
    </tbody>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
        <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal">$875.00</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
        <td class="total-value"><div id="total">$875.00</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Amount Paid</td>
        <td class="total-value"><textarea id="paid">$0.00</textarea></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
        <td colspan="2" class="total-line balance">Balance Due</td>
        <td class="total-value balance"><div class="due">$875.00</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

with jQuery, I want to select the contents of div Ids, subtotal,total,amount paid and balance due.

There is this button i use to trigger the jQuery

```
<input type="button" id="example" value="submit" onClick="storeAndShowTableValues()"/>
```

I already tried to do it like this, but it's not working.

```
var qwer=$("#example").closest("tr").find(".subtotal");
```

How do i do this?

Comment: It would be more helpful if the button was actually in the HTML, how are we supposed to know what the closest TR is ?

Comment: Also, you have an element with the ID `subtotal`, not a class, and if that's the element you want to access, it's just `$('#subtotal')`

Comment: I updated the code. So how do i actually get the value of those to JavaScript variables?

Answer (score 0):

```
var subtotal = $('#subtotal').text(),
    total = $('#total').text(),
    paid = $('#paid').val(),
    due = $('.due').text();
```

For Something like this?

```js
$(document).on('click', '#example', function(e) {
  var subtotal = parseFloat($('#subtotal').text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')),
      total = parseFloat($('#total').text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')),
      paid = parseFloat($('#paid').val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')),
      due = parseFloat($('.due').text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));
  
  
  
  $('ul').empty();
  var all = { subtotal: subtotal, total: total, paid: paid, due: due }
  for (x in all) {
    var ax = all[x];
    $('ul').append($('<li />', { text: x + ': ' + ax }))
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="items">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th>SlNo</th>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Unit Cost</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item-row">
    <td class="item-name">
    <div class="delete-wpr"><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="slno"/></td>           
    <td><input type="text" class="cost"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty"/></td>
    <!--  <td><span class="price"></span></td>-->
    <td class="price"> </td>
   </tr>
   <input type="button" id="example" value="submit" />
  </tbody>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
   <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
   <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal">$875.00</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
   <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
   <td class="total-value"><div id="total">$900.00</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
   <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Amount Paid</td>
   <td class="total-value"><textarea id="paid">$0.00</textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
   <td colspan="2" class="total-line balance">Balance Due</td>
   <td class="total-value balance"><div class="due">$420.00</div></td>
  </tr>
 </table>

<ul></ul>
```

Or how about this?!

```
function getValues() {
    var cost = parseFloat($('.cost').val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')),
        qty = parseFloat($('.qty').val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));
    return {
        cost: cost == cost ? cost : 0,
        qty: qty == qty ? qty : 1,
        subtotal: parseFloat($('#subtotal').text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')),
        total: parseFloat($('#total').text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')),
        paid: parseFloat($('#paid').val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')),
        due: parseFloat($('.due').text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''))
    }
}
```

```js
function getValues() {
 var cost = parseFloat($('.cost').val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')),
  qty = parseFloat($('.qty').val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')),
        subt = parseFloat($('#subtotal').text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''));
  if (this.subt == undefined) this.subt = subt
 return {
  cost: cost == cost ? cost : 0,
  qty: qty == qty ? qty : 1,
  subtotal: cost && qty ? subt : this.subt,
  total: parseFloat($('#total').text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')),
  paid: parseFloat($('#paid').val().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')),
  due: parseFloat($('.due').text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''))
 }
}
function calc() {
 var v = getValues(),
  newSub = (v.cost * v.qty) + v.subtotal,
  newTot = newSub,
  newDue = newTot - v.paid;
 console.log(v, '\r\n', '(',v.cost,' * ',v.qty,')', '+', v.subtotal, (v.cost * v.qty) + v.subtotal)
 $('#subtotal').text('$' + newSub);
 $('#total').text('$' + newTot);
 $('.due').text('$' + newDue);
}

calc();

$(document)
 .on('change', '.cost, .qty, #paid', calc)
 .on('click', '#example', calc)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="items">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <th>SlNo</th>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th>Unit Cost</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
    <th>Price</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="item-row">
    <td class="item-name">
    <div class="delete-wpr"><a class="delete" href="javascript:;" title="Remove row">X</a></div></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="slno"/></td>           
    <td><input type="text" class="cost"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" class="qty"/></td>
    <!--  <td><span class="price"></span></td>-->
    <td class="price"> </td>
   </tr>
   <input type="button" id="example" value="submit" />
  </tbody>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
   <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Subtotal</td>
   <td class="total-value"><div id="subtotal">$875.00</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
   <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Total</td>
   <td class="total-value"><div id="total">$875.00</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
   <td colspan="2" class="total-line">Amount Paid</td>
   <td class="total-value"><textarea id="paid">$0.00</textarea></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2" class="blank"> </td>
   <td colspan="2" class="total-line balance">Balance Due</td>
   <td class="total-value balance"><div class="due">$875.00</div></td>
  </tr>
 </table>

<ul></ul>
```